# What one-syllable adjectives can take "more" as comparative?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, comparatives

I teach ESL.  My job is to stop people saying "more big" instead of "bigger".  "Fun", as noted on this site, is an exception, I think because the noun, meaning "amusement", is on the way to becoming an adjective, but is not all the way there, which is why "funner" is impossible, and "a fun activity" is informal register.  It strikes me that, while "falser" is listed in the dictionary, "more false" is considerably more ok than "more big".

One reason for this seems to me that, if an adjective *can* take -er, then the more common it is, the more strongly it prefers the terminations.  Another reason might be whether it is scalar, or gradable. English tends to regard certain words as absolute, yes-or-no propositions. Something is either false or it isn't, so "more false" has the force of "further down the road towards being false". This would also explain the expression "more dead than alive", where "more dead" is technically incorrect.

The expression "deader than a door-nail" is explicable because it is an expression, which may have become popular in part because of the comic-sounding idea of "deader".  Examples like "This town is the deadest I've ever lived in; everything is closed after 9pm" is more to be explained as "dead" now has a figurative sense, "lively", which is scalable.

What other ideas do people have to explain such exceptional comparatives, and what other interesting examples are there?

Comment: You know the actual rule, right? Not sure scalable is the right term. True and false are set terms but one thing can be truer than something else. However, although you may say falser, philosophically, is it valid to say that something can be falser than something else? [His statement was falser than his brother's.] Only in some very exceptional circumstances. I reckon you give students the list of the most used irregular comparatives, and then explain about things like baddest, for example.

Comment: fun is a noun. But I don't think a fun activity is informal. It's just using a noun adjectivally. That is very common in English.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the distinction between "[X]er" and "more [X]" falls more under usage than grammar. It's not *wrong* to say "more big", or indeed to say "extraneouser." It's just not done. It's intriguing to analyze *why*, but the answers might always align to quantifiable "rules."

Comment: There is also the separate case where we "mention" adjectives: "I would say the package was more  *big* than *enormous*.

Comment: @AndyBonner Actually, "it's just not done" is a good description of ungrammaticality. There isn't any "incorrect" (except in grammar school), but there is ungrammatical, and the big thing is that ungrammatical sentences **don't** happen. Figuring out why is the fun part.;

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree. They don't happen with native speakers, full stop. [But the folks I teach, non-native-speaking learners of English sure do come up with ungrammatical sentences. Often very interesting ones, which is fun too!]

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I agree, too. I taught ESL for 6 years (3 in night school while I was getting my MA, then 3 more full time) before going back to school for my PhD in syntax. I found that when I was learning syntax, I could always find counterexamples to proposed rules just by remembering how foreign students (who were by far the smartest and most highly-motivated students) would deal with it.

Comment: Thanks. ESL teachers have to help our students advance their careers;  the same thing you can say if you have a native accent is going to be a mistake if you have a foreign accent. For fun's status as an adjective, this link is not bad: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-says-fun-cant-be-an-adjective.  I agree that one idea is as false as another; I suppose one black-hearted villain can be falser than another, but again that introduces a new sense.  And yes, teaching advanced, talented English learners is an education in grammar and syntax without equal.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think the distinction between "just not done" and "not grammatical" is that the former refers to whether something is idiomatic, while the latter refers to general rules that tend to be applied consistently.

Comment: That may be the way some people use the terms. But they're hardly well-defined.

Comment: Sometimes you need to say *more red* and not redder: This purple is more red than blue to me. Any more red clothes and you'll burn up, Dear.